# Android Studio: Location Marker not showing up

Tags: android, google-maps

The below code is run on an AVD.  The AVD browser opens the link through an application and shows google maps, but doesn't display the marker.  The browser has the below 'String url' in it's url.  When I press enter the url goes to the exact location and creates the marker location.  I want to have the browser automatically bring me to the marker location and display a marker without having to click on the url and press enter.  Any help is appreciated.

```
String url = "https://maps.google.com/maps?z=10&t=m&q=loc:"+latitude+"+"+longitude+"";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Uri.encode(url));
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Removed the Uri.encode(url) and it seems to work OK now.